# How to remove only the first occurrence of a line in a file using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have the following file

```
titi
tata
toto
tata
```

If I execute

```
sed -i "/tat/d" file.txt
```

It will remove all the lines containing `tat`. The command returns:

```
titi
toto
```

but I want to remove only the first line that occurs in the file containing `tat`:

```
titi
toto
tata
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to remove all first ocurrences of lines that appear at least twice?

Comment: @fedorqui only the first occurence of the line and not all the occurence of the line

Comment: But just for "tata" or for all of them? Meaning, you want to remove the first occurrence of "tata" and that's all or you want to remove all the first occurrences of all lines appearing at least twice?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could make use of two-address form:

```
sed '0,/tat/{/tat/d;}' inputfile
```

This would delete the first occurrence of the pattern.

Quoting from `info sed`:

```
 A line number of `0' can be used in an address specification like
 `0,/REGEXP/' so that `sed' will try to match REGEXP in the first
 input line too.  In other words, `0,/REGEXP/' is similar to
 `1,/REGEXP/', except that if ADDR2 matches the very first line of
 input the `0,/REGEXP/' form will consider it to end the range,
 whereas the `1,/REGEXP/' form will match the beginning of its
 range and hence make the range span up to the _second_ occurrence
 of the regular expression.
```

Comment: I think this the best answer. Thank you

Comment: @jaypal I'll a snippet from `info sed` to the answer.

Comment: @devnull Oh thanks for that, I wasn't aware of such benefit. +1 for that piece of info! :)

Comment: Or shorter `sed '0,/tat/{//d;}' inputfile`.

Comment: @SLePort nitpicking but `sed '0,/tat/{//d}' inputfile` is even shorter ;-) But 1000x thanks for teaching me about the `//` construction.

Answer (score 5):

If you can use `awk`, then this makes it:

```
$ awk '/tata/ && !f{f=1; next} 1' file
titi
toto
tata
```

To save your result in the current file, do

```
awk '...' file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file
```

#### Explanation

Let's activate a flag whenever `tata` is matched for the first time and skip the line. From that moment, keep not-skipping these lines.

- `/tata/` matches lines that contain the string `tata`.
- `{f=1; next}` sets flag `f` as 1 and then skips the line.
- `!f{}` if the flag `f` is set, skip this block.
- `1`, as a True value, performs the default awk action: `{print $0}`.

### Another approach, by [Tom Fenech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088135/tom-fenech)

```
awk '!/tata/ || f++' file
```

`||` stands for OR, so this condition is true, and hence prints the line, whenever any of these happens:

- `tata` is not found in the line.
- `f++` is true. This is the tricky part: first time f is 0 as default, so first `f++` will return False and not print the line. From that moment, it will increment from an integer value and will be True.

Comment: or for the ultimate in readability: `awk '!/tata/ || f++' file`

Comment: Oh that's very bright, @TomFenech! I would consider editing my answer to include this approach.

Comment: It's hardly the most self-documenting of approaches but by all means, go ahead :)

Comment: @TomFenech `awk '!/tata/ || f++'` This one, is just up my alley. I love those short marvels. So I add this to my favorite list. I did not know that it just skips testing if some is true, so that `f` is not incremented of there are no `tata`.  If you like to remove the two first hits of a word, just do `awk '!/tata/ || f++==2'`

Comment: Thanks for the attribution fedorqui, and good explanation :)  @Jotne I'm glad you liked it. As in most languages `||` is short-circuiting so the second part isn't evaluated when the first is true.

Comment: @TomFenech I do see that `awk '!/tata/ || f++'` do the same as `awk '!/tata/ || f--'` and if you like to delete second hits, `awk -v f=1 '!/tata/ || f--' and third hits `awk -v f=2 '!/tata/ || f--' etc

Comment: Or better `awk -v f=2 '!/tata/ || --f'` for second etc

Answer (score 4):

Here's the general way to do it:

```
$ cat file
     1  titi
     2  tata
     3  toto
     4  tata
     5  foo
     6  tata
     7  bar
$
$ awk '/tat/{ if (++f == 1) next} 1' file
     1  titi
     3  toto
     4  tata
     5  foo
     6  tata
     7  bar
$
$ awk '/tat/{ if (++f == 2) next} 1' file
     1  titi
     2  tata
     3  toto
     5  foo
     6  tata
     7  bar
$
$ awk '/tat/{ if (++f ~ /^(1|2)$/) next} 1' file
     1  titi
     3  toto
     5  foo
     6  tata
     7  bar
```

Note that with the above approach you can skip whatever occurrence(s) of an RE you like (1st, 2nd, 1st and 2nd, whatever) and you only specify the RE once (as opposed to having to duplicate it for some alternative solutions).

Clear, simple, obvious, easily maintainable, extensible, etc....

Comment: Best answer by far, the others didn't even work for me. Great flexibility in this one!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it with `sed`:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\ntat[^\n]*//' file
titi
toto
tata
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/pattern/{x;//!d;x}' file
```

Print all lines other than those containing the pattern as normal. Otherwise if the line contains the pattern and hold space does not (the first occurrence), delete that line.

Answer (score -1):

You may find the first matching line number with `grep` and pass it to `sed` for deletion.

```
sed "$((grep -nm1 tat file.txt || echo 1000000000:) | cut -f 1 -d:) d" file.txt
```

`grep -n` combined with `cut` finds the line number to be deleted. `grep -m1` ensures at most one line number is found. `echo` handles the case when there is no match so as not to return an empty result. `sed "[line number] d"` deletes the line.

Comment: Please roll your two answers into one answer, separated by a title or bold heading illustrating the two ways to do it, and pros/cons of each.  Code only answers are low quality and subject to deletion, there should at least be 1 or two sentences explaining what question you are addressing, what it's doing in laymans terms, and optionally other pitfalls.   See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers  Address these and I'll remove the comment and downvote.