# How to delete first 10 lines containing certain string?

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose i have a file with this structures

```
1001.txt
1002.txt
1003.txt
1004.txt
1005.txt
2001.txt
2002.txt
2003.txt
...
```

Now how can I delete first 10 numbers of line which start with '2'? There might be more than 10 lines start with '2'.

I know I can use `grep '^2' file | wc -l` to find number of lines which start with '2'. But how to delete the first 10 numbers of line?

Comment: You might find a clue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696871/how-to-remove-only-the-first-occurrence-of-a-line-in-a-file-using-sed

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe your list through this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -p -e '$_="" if (/^2/ and $i++ >= 10)'
```

Comment: how do I specifiy which file to check?

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk. Testing with value 2 as your data only had 3 lines of related data. Replace the latter 2 with a 10.

```
$ awk '/^2/ && ++c<=2 {next} 1' file
1001.txt
1002.txt
1003.txt
1004.txt
1005.txt
2003.txt
.
.
.
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '/^2/ && ++c<=2 {   # if it starts with a 2 and counter still got iterations left
    next                  # skip to the next record
} 1                       # (else) output
' file
```

Comment: Or, invert the logic: `awk '!/^2/ || ++c>10'`

Comment: i got the result just like you. but nothing change in the file.

Comment: It doesn't change the source file, you need to redirect the output to a new file. It's safer.

Comment: how to do it? `> new_file` ?

Comment: Yes. `awk '...' file > new_file`

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't understand what you mean?

Comment: what if i want to do this more than 1 times? do I need to keep `awk '...' file > new_file` and output it to a new file?

Comment: than i will have n files?

Comment: If you want them to a single `new_file`: `awk '...' file* > new_file`. If you want them all to different files you need to script around the awk, for example: `for f in file* ; do awk '...' $f > new_$f ; done` (add appropriate quoting around the `$f` if needed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149008/discussion-between-pwan-and-james-brown).

Comment: @JamesBrown `awk -F '/^1/ && ++c<=2 {next} 1' '/^2/ && ++d<=1 {next} 1' test.txt > new.txt` is not working....

Comment: No doubt. You have `-F` but no value for it and two different programs sequentially. Awk does not work that way.

Comment: so how do I do multiple operation in only one awk. I'm trying to do the 2 operation from a file to another...

Comment: Untested, but I'd say: `awk '( /^1/ && ++c<=2 ) || ( /^2/ && ++d<=1 ) {next} 1'` ie. two conditions and an OR (`||`)  in between.

Answer (score 0):

awk alternative:

```
awk '{ if (substr($0,1,1)=="2") { count++ } if ( count > 10 || substr($0,1,1)!="2") { print $0 } }' filename
```

If the first character of the line is 2, increment a counter. Then only print the line if count is greater than 10 or the first character isn't 2.